# admin change_view is being called twice

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a chance to keep django admin from calling `change_view` twice when clicking "save and continue editing"?

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SomeAdminForm
    
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url = "", extra_context = None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        print("test")
        return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context = extra_context,)
```

prints test once, when entering the change form layout, prints test twice when clicking "save and continue editing". I run a costly query inside that `change_view` function, that needs to be displayed in the admin change form. But I want it to only run once. Any ideas?

Comment: The `save and continue reading` does this twice once by saving, and once when rerendering the form for editing.

Comment: any way to get around it?